# C++ Error: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, class, linker

I looked through the other questions that also contained these errors. I was not able to find a solution from those questions. Some answers said certain functions weren't implemented but my functions are. I only get the title error when I try to run the program from the VS2012 command line. When I run the program from the IDE, I have no errors and everything is fine.

### Visual Studio 2012 Project

- [TTH.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ukgkhbglkvyv81/TTH.zip)

### Imgur

- [Capture_CMD.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz7px.png)

### useTTH.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "tth.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string message;
    string choice;

    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter a message: ";
        getline(cin, message);

        tth tthObject;
        tthObject.getMessage(message);
        tthObject.encryptMessageOnlyLetters();

        cout << endl;
        cout << "Encrypt another message? (Yes/No)" << endl;
        cout << "> ";
        getline(cin, choice);
        cout << endl;
    }
    while(choice.substr(0, 1) == "Y" || choice.substr(0, 1) == "y");

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

### tth.h

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class tth
{
    public:
        tth();
        void getMessage(string messageP);
        void setMessageOnlyLettersNumberOf16Blocks();
        void encryptMessageOnlyLetters();
        void messageOnlyLettersToFourByFourLetters();
        void matchLetterToNumber();
        void calculateAndShowRunningTotalFourByFourNumbers();
        void shiftRowsAccordingly();
        void calculateAndShowRunningTotalTemp();
        void matchNumberToLetter();
        void showFourLetterHashNumbers();


    private:
        string message;
        vector<char> messageOnlyLetters;
        int runningTotal[4];
        char fourLetterHash[4];
        int messageLength;
        int messageOnlyLettersNumberOf16Blocks;
        char fourByFourLetters[4][4];
        int fourByFourNumbers[4][4];
        int temp[4][4];
};
```

### tth.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include "tth.h"

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// tth()
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Constructor for the tth class.
// Initializes the elements of the private integer array 'runningTotal' to 0.
// Initializes the elements of the private char array 'fourLetterHash' to 'A'.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tth::tth()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        runningTotal[i] = 0;
        fourLetterHash[i] = 'A';
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getMessage(string messageP)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// A public function of the tth class.
// Sets the value of the private string variable 'message' to the value of the string 'messageP' parameter.
// Gives the private char vector 'messageOnlyLetters' only letter elements of the 'message' variable. 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void tth::getMessage(string messageP)
{
    message = messageP;
    messageLength = message.length();

    for(int i = 0; i < messageLength; i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(message[i]))
        {
            messageOnlyLetters.push_back(message[i]);
        }
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setMessageOnlyLettersNumberOf16Blocks()
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// A public function of the tth class.
// Pads the messageOnlyLetters vector with a number 'A' elements equal to modulo 16 of the size of the vector.
// Sets the private int variable 'messageOnlyLettersNumberOf16Blocks' to the quotient of the vector size and 16.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void tth::setMessageOnlyLettersNumberOf16Blocks()
{
    int messageOnlyLettersModulo = messageOnlyLetters.size() % 16;

    while(messageOnlyLettersModulo != 0)
    {
        messageOnlyLetters.push_back('A');
        messageOnlyLettersModulo = messageOnlyLetters.size() % 16;
    }

    messageOnlyLettersNumberOf16Blocks = messageOnlyLetters.size() / 16;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// encryptMessageOnlyLetters()
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// A public function of the tth class.
// Executes the 'setMessageOnlyLettersNumberOf16Blocks()' once.
// Executes other functions of the tth class a number of times equal to 'messageOnlyLettersNumberOf16Blocks'.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void tth::encryptMessageOnlyLetters()
{
    setMessageOnlyLettersNumberOf16Blocks();

    for (int i = 0; i < messageOnlyLettersNumberOf16Blocks; i++)
    {
        messageOnlyLettersToFourByFourLetters();
        matchLetterToNumber();
        calculateAndShowRunningTotalFourByFourNumbers();
        cout << endl;
        shiftRowsAccordingly();
        calculateAndShowRunningTotalTemp();
        cout << endl;
        matchNumberToLetter();
        showFourLetterHashNumbers();
        cout << endl;
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// messageOnlyLettersToFourByFourLetters()
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// A public function of the tth class.
// Sets the elements of the private char 2D array 'fourByFourLetters' to the elements of 'messageOnlyLetters'.
// Reduces the size of a non-empty messageOnlyLetters by 16 elements.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void tth::messageOnlyLettersToFourByFourLetters()
{
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            fourByFourLetters[i][j] = messageOnlyLetters[count];
            count++;
        }
    }

    if(!(messageOnlyLetters.empty()))
    {
        messageOnlyLetters.erase(messageOnlyLetters.begin(), messageOnlyLetters.begin() + 16);
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// matchLetterToNumber()
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// A public function of the tth class.
// Sets the elements of the private int 2D array 'fourByFourNumbers' to a number 0 - 25.
// The number is determined by the ASCII value of a 'fourByFourLetters' element.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void tth::matchLetterToNumber()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            switch(static_cast<int>(fourByFourLetters[i][j]))
            {
                case 65:
                case 97:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 0;
                    break;
                case 66:
                case 98:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 1;
                    break;
                case 67:
                case 99:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 2;
                    break;
                case 68:
                case 100:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 3;
                    break;
                case 69:
                case 101:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 4;
                    break;
                case 70:
                case 102:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 5;
                    break;
                case 71:
                case 103:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 6;
                    break;
                case 72:
                case 104:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 7;
                    break;
                case 73:
                case 105:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 8;
                    break;
                case 74:
                case 106:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 9;
                    break;
                case 75:
                case 107:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 10;
                    break;
                case 76:
                case 108:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 11;
                    break;
                case 77:
                case 109:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 12;
                    break;
                case 78:
                case 110:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 13;
                    break;
                case 79:
                case 111:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 14;
                    break;
                case 80:
                case 112:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 15;
                    break;
                case 81:
                case 113:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 16;
                    break;
                case 82:
                case 114:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 17;
                    break;
                case 83:
                case 115:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 18;
                    break;
                case 84:
                case 116:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 19;
                    break;
                case 85:
                case 117:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 20;
                    break;
                case 86:
                case 118:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 21;
                    break;
                case 87:
                case 119:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 22;
                    break;
                case 88:
                case 120:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 23;
                    break;
                case 89:
                case 121:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 24;
                    break;
                case 90:
                case 122:
                    fourByFourNumbers[i][j] = 25;
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << "Hmmmm";
            }
        }
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// calculateAndShowRunningTotalFourByFourNumbers()
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// A public function of the tth class.
// Calculates and sets the elements of 'runningTotal' using an accumulator with 'fourByFourNumbers'.
// Displays a command line message with each element of 'runningTotal'.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void tth::calculateAndShowRunningTotalFourByFourNumbers()
{
    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            runningTotal[i] = runningTotal[i] + fourByFourNumbers[j][i];
        }

        runningTotal[i] = runningTotal[i] % 26;
        cout << runningTotal[i] << " ";
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// shiftRowsAccordingly()
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// A public function of the tth class.
// Sets the elements of the private int 2D array 'temp' to a rearranged version of 'fourByFourNumbers'.
// Elements of rows 1 - 3 are shifted in a circular pattern.
// Row 1 elements are shifted to the left by 1 index. Row 2 elements are shifted to the left by 2 indicies.
// Row 3 elements are shifted to the left by 3 indicies. Row 4 elements are swapped: 1 <> 4 and 2 <> 3.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void tth::shiftRowsAccordingly()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                if(j == 3)
                {
                    temp[i][j] = fourByFourNumbers[i][j - 3];
                }
                else
                {
                    temp[i][j] = fourByFourNumbers[i][j + 1];
                }
            }
            else if(i == 1)
            {
                if(j == 2)
                {
                    temp[i][j] = fourByFourNumbers[i][j - 2];
                }
                else if(j == 3)
                {
                    temp[i][j] = fourByFourNumbers[i][j - 2];
                }
                else
                {
                    temp[i][j] = fourByFourNumbers[i][j + 2];
                }
            }
            else if(i == 2)
            {
                if(j == 1)
                {
                    temp[i][j] = fourByFourNumbers[i][j - 1];
                }
                else if(j == 2)
                {
                    temp[i][j] = fourByFourNumbers[i][j - 1];
                }
                else if(j == 3)
                {
                    temp[i][j] = fourByFourNumbers[i][j - 1];
                }
                else
                {
                    temp[i][j] = fourByFourNumbers[i][j + 3];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(j == 1)
                {
                    temp[i][j] = fourByFourNumbers[i][j + 1];
                }
                else if(j == 2)
                {
                    temp[i][j] = fourByFourNumbers[i][j - 1];
                }
                else if(j == 3)
                {
                    temp[i][j] = fourByFourNumbers[i][j - 3];
                }
                else
                {
                    temp[i][j] = fourByFourNumbers[i][j + 3];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// calculateAndShowRunningTotalTemp()
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// A public function of the tth class.
// Calculates and sets the elements of 'runningTotal' using an accumulator with 'temp'.
// Displays a command line message with each element of 'runningTotal'.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void tth::calculateAndShowRunningTotalTemp()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            runningTotal[i] = runningTotal[i] + temp[j][i];
        }

        runningTotal[i] = runningTotal[i] % 26;
        cout << runningTotal[i] << " ";
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// matchNumberToLetter()
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// A public function of the tth class.
// Sets the elements of the private char 2D array 'fourLetterHash' to a letter A - Z.
// The letter is determined by the value of a 'runningTotal' element.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void tth::matchNumberToLetter()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        switch(runningTotal[i])
        {
            case 0:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'A';
                break;
            case 1:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'B';
                break;
            case 2:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'C';
                break;
            case 3:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'D';
                break;
            case 4:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'E';
                break;
            case 5:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'F';
                break;
            case 6:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'G';
                break;
            case 7:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'H';
                break;
            case 8:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'I';
                break;
            case 9:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'J';
                break;
            case 10:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'K';
                break;
            case 11:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'L';
                break;
            case 12:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'M';
                break;
            case 13:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'N';
                break;
            case 14:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'O';
                break;
            case 15:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'P';
                break;
            case 16:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'Q';
                break;
            case 17:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'R';
                break;
            case 18:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'S';
                break;
            case 19:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'T';
                break;
            case 20:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'U';
                break;
            case 21:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'V';
                break;
            case 22:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'W';
                break;
            case 23:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'X';
                break;
            case 24:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'Y';
                break;
            case 25:
                fourLetterHash[i] = 'Z';
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Hmmmm";
        }
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// showFourLetterHashNumbers()
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// A public function of the tth class.
// Displays a command line message with each element of 'fourLetterHash'.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void tth::showFourLetterHashNumbers()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << fourLetterHash[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

## EDIT

Gah. I put so much effort into this post just to find out it was a simple problem with command line compiling. Thanks for the answers.

### Answer

Use the command below to compile the definition file and main program file.

```
cl tth.cpp useTTH.cpp
```

Comment: Please don't just post code dumps here. They aren't helpful to future visitors in the slightest, which is one of the goals of SO.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I wanted to avoid posting just the code in the text but I can't include more than 2 links with my reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]You should compile both `tth.cpp` and `useTTH.cpp`

with command line:

`cl tth.cpp useTTH.cpp`

Comment: Of course it was just a simple problem like that. Kicking myself so hard right now. The spam filter was keeping me from posting so soon after a comment to us2012. Sorry if my silence prompted the extra edits. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include all your source files in your compiler command. As `tth.cpp` is not included, it cannot find the symbols corresponding to the functions/variables defined there.

Comment: I am embarrassed at how much effort I put into making this post just for the problem to be so simple.